# Asset copy not completing

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a zip file in my asset folder and when trying to copy this file to the external download folder I cannot open it. It seems as if the file copy does not finish as it is a few kb short of what it should be.

I am using the following code to achieve this:

```
using (Stream stream = activity.Assets.Open (PINPAD_FOLDER + "/" + file)) 
{
   stream.CopyTo (System.IO.File.Create (outputPath));
   stream.Close ();
}
```

Output folder is:

```
string outputPath = Path.Combine (Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).AbsolutePath, filename);
```

All I need is to get the path to this zip file from my application which does not seem possible from the Asset directory as we can only get a stream back. Hence I am having to copy it to a directory I know the path of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
using (Stream stream = activity.Assets.Open (PINPAD_FOLDER + "/" + file)) 
{
    using(var fileStream = System.IO.File.Create (outputPath))
    {
        stream.CopyTo(fileStream );
    }
}
```